# OpenCV: draw a white(!) circle in CV_16UC1 mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to draw a white circle in an matrix of type CV_16UC1.
That is basically what I do:

```
cv::Mat bla => Type CV_16UC1
cv::circle(bla, cv::Point(15, 15), 1, COLOR, 20);
```

I tried for Color:

```
cv::Scalar(0,0,0)
cv::Scalar(255,255,255)
UINT_MAX
```

but everything turns up black... any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly that `C1` means one channel image. Try to use a color with one demension: `cv::Scalar(0xffff)`

I use `0xffff` because the `16U` means 16 (unsigned) bits per channel.